# I underquoted my current salary so ended up with less salary at a new job. How do I recover from this?

Tags: salary

I underquoted my previous salary so ended up with less salary at a new job I already started. I guess I was so caught up with so many things that this mistake happened.

How do I recover from this? Should I be happy with what I have now or go back to the boss and renegotiate?

Comment: Never underquote your most recent salary.

Answer (score 9):

You've negotiated, signed contract(s), started and now want to renegotiate as you realise you've accepted less than you made before?  I think that unless the job has turned significantly different to that described, or you have some unique skill/knowledge only you can bring to the role, you're a bit too late.

You risk the job you're still likely in trial period for, and also risk looking bad if you actually admit why you want to renegotiate.

I think you just need to move forward, and next time do the math before you get an offer, so you know where you stand.

Answer (score 2):

You clearly made it a mistake during negotiations and now you have to live with the consequences (that's what "freedom" is actually all about). However, mistakes happen all the time and maybe you can turn this into a learning and growth opportunity. A good method is the following

1. **Acknowledge**: admit to yourself that you made a boo-boo. It's up to you to take control of the situation. You are in charge of managing this.
2. **Triage**: Contain the immediate damage. In your case, that's probably not relevant since the damage already happened and it's not getting any worse.
3. **Find and implement a stable long term fix**. In your case you want more money (I think). This is now completely independent on what you earned before, but it's all about working compensation in your new role. There are plenty of posts on this site on how to get a raise: do market research, align with your management on goals & metrics, get the job done, document carefully and clearly that you hit the metrics, etc.
4. **Learn**: Analyze what you did wrong. You under-quoted your current salary. Why did you do this? What where you hoping to achieve in doing so? How did the actual outcome compared to your initial goal? What would you do differently next time?